Regex multiple matches example in python . how do I implement this?
I have to do a lot of text matching and I am relying on regex which seems great at this.
This is the text I am searching below: Note that there is hierarchy where Test1_1 is under Test1_1, Test1_1_1 is under Test1_1, Test1_1_2 is under Test1_1
Also Test1_2 is under Test1 and Test1_2_1 is under Test1_2 and Test1_2_2 is under Test1_2

   <Class Test1>\n
    <Class Test1_1>\n
      <Class Test1_1_1>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n
         ......
      <Class Test1_1_2>
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  
        ........
   <Class Test1_2>\n
      <Class Test1_2_1>
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n
         ......
      <Class Test1_2_2>
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  
        ........
  

I want be able to get the 2 IP's that are a part of the test provided that they are under the correct heirarchy. So for example, I want to be able to search for all testAmplitude under Test1, Test1_1, Test1_1_1 and get 10.7.10.9 and 10.7.10.18 both. I show an example in python below.
I am using Python. The closest i could come up with is :
  import re
    rec_pattern = re.compile(  
        f"<CLASS TEST1>.+?"  #
        f"<CLASS TEST1_1>.+?"  #
        f"<CLASS TEST1_1_1>"  # 
        "("  #
        "(?:.+?"  #
        f"<FUNCTION testAmplitude AT (?:.*?)>"
        ")*" #
        ")"  #
        , re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL) 
    matches = re.findall(rec_pattern, self.output_text)

The regex pattern would be:
<CLASS TEST1>.+<CLASS TEST1_1>.+?<CLASS TEST1_1_1>((?:.+?<FUNCTION testAmplitude AT (?:.*?)>)*)

This gets me below in 1 match(not 2 seperate matches and extra text. I only want the IP's in 2 seperate matches).

      <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>
      <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>

How can i just get 10.7.10.9 and 10.7.10.18 in 2 separate matches? I tried non greedy approach and it didn't work.
The other thing which I found hard to tackle is that websites like this https://regex101.com/ and https://regexr.com/ only seem to support 1 match which makes it hard to test and find out correct answer. The given solution was to test with these websites, find 1 match (it only supports 1 match) and then I have to test in python to find multiple matches using findall. Is there a way to get these websites or are you familiar with other websites that can get multiple matches?? Am i getting this question wrong or missing something?

Do you always have exactly two IPs to match, how about e.g. matches = re.findall(r'(?i)(?:<Class Test1(?:_1)*>[^<]*){3}<Function testAmplitude at \b([\d.]+)>[^<]*<Function testAmplitude at \b([\d.]+)>', my_str) (Python demo at tio.run) or regex101 demo

Do you have to do this using a regexp? It's best to use an XML library to process XML.

@Nitrous One more demo at tio.run with exact hierarchy...

@Barmar its not xml. its output from pytest. I could do xml also actually but there a lot of different types of output so leaned on regex

@bobblebubble nice! Will take some time to understand how you did this.

If the difference in between the two IPs is the last part ("host identifier"), one way to do this is to write your patterns using:
\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d
\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d{2}

such as:
(?im)^\s*(<function\s+.*\sat\s+(\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d))\b\s*>
(?im)^\s*(<function\s+.*\sat\s+(\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d{2}))\b\s*>

Example for the first IP:
import re

st = """
   <Class Test1>\n
    <Class Test1_1>\n
      <Class Test1_1_1>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n
         ......
      <Class Test1_1_2>
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  
        ........
   <Class Test1_2>\n
      <Class Test1_2_1>
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n
         ......
      <Class Test1_2_2>
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  

"""

regex = r'(?im)^\s*(<function\s+.*\sat\s+(\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d))\b\s*>'

print(re.findall(regex, st))


which gives you a list of tuples:
[('<Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9'), ('<Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9', '10.7.10.9')]


If you only need the entire line, the capture groups can be removed, such as with:
(?im)^[^\r\n]*<function\s+.*\sat\s+\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b\s*>\s*$

Example for the second IP
import re

st = """
   <Class Test1>\n
    <Class Test1_1>\n
      <Class Test1_1_1>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n
         ......
      <Class Test1_1_2>
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  
        ........
   <Class Test1_2>\n
      <Class Test1_2_1>
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>\n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n
         ......
      <Class Test1_2_2>
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.9>  \n
        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  

"""

regex = r'(?im)^[^\r\n]*<function\s+.*\sat\s+\d{2}\.\d\.\d{2}\.\d{2}\b\s*>\s*$'

print(re.findall(regex, st))


That returns:
['        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n', '        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n', '        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n', '        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n', '        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  ', '        <Function testAmplitude at 10.7.10.18>\n', '        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>\n', '        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18>\n', '        <Function testAverage at 10.7.10.18>   \n', '        <Function testSquareWave at 10.7.10.18> \n  \n\n']


The issue i think with this approach is that I cannot verify the hierarchy of the test. I want to be able to verify the hierarchy and get the output at the same time. If i cannot verify the hierarchy, it might be a duplicate testName under another test hierarchy.

Could you also comment on this  'The other thing which I found hard to tackle is that websites like this https://regex101.com/ and https://regexr.com/ only seem to support 1 match which makes it hard to test and find out correct answer. The given solution was to test with these websites, find 1 match (it only supports 1 match) and then I have to test in python to find multiple matches using findall. Is there a way to get these websites or are you familiar with other websites that can get multiple matches?? Am i getting this question wrong or missing something?'

@Nitrous Your second comment: link? Is the ending \n literal a problem for you?

I got around the \n. I think in my test code at https://regex101.com/r/isOQ88/1 i added the \n manually. Actually you might be right, it might have ended up working with multiple matches. I kept switching between python and regex and got a little frustrated. Let me go back and test again.

@Nitrous Do you only have three levels of Class Tests?

That is correct. I only have 3 levels of Class Test

@Nitrous About your first comment, it's best to first break the string and get the "hierarchy" info, then incorporate your regex patterns to get the details. Otherwise, the regex only solution would become complex.

That actually makes a lot of sense..........THANK YOU!  I think the major issue for me was that the regex was becoming very complex but first doing a regex for the Test and then doing another regex for the IP's totally makes sense

The regex would be complex.
I ended up splitting the text into 2 searches instead of 1
I am doing <Class Test1>.+?<Class Test1_1>.+?<Class Test1_1_1>.+?(<Function.+?)(?=<Class) to get the functions under the test hierarchy and doing another regex to get the IP's. Thanks to @123 (for the extended discussion in comments)
